# how to pass more arguments to php array_walk?

Tags: php

I want to know how to pass more arguments to my array_walk..

```
$addresses = array('www.google.com', 'www.yahoo.com', 'www.microsoft.com');
$a = 'hey';
$b = 'hey';
array_walk($addresses, array($this, '_handle'), $a, $b); // $a and $b parameters doesn't get passed

private function _handle($address,$a, $b) {
       echo $address; // www.google.com
       echo $a // 012
       echo $b // 012
}
```

How do I pass parameters anyway? I have to pass more than 5 parameters.. please teach me.. thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The third parameter is a mixed data type. If you have many parameters, I would suggest putting them into an Array - perhaps an associative array to name them. You'd then pull them back out of that param:

```
$addresses = array('www.google.com', 'www.yahoo.com', 'www.microsoft.com');
$params = array('first','second');
array_walk($addresses, array($this, '_handle'), $params);

private function _handle($address,$count, $params) {
       echo $address; // www.google.com
       echo $params[0]; // first
       echo $params[1]; // second
}
```

Comment: ohh ok.. sorry i don't understand the php manual. it says userdata and i don't have any idea that it's an array.. thanks man

Comment: @Kevin: userdata *can* be an array, it can be whatever you want.  It can be an int, a string, an object, an array, etc.  An array is used so you can have multiple values.

Answer (score 5):

It will only allow one argument for user data. I suggest passing your values as an array.

```
array_walk($addresses, array($this, '_handle'), array($a, $b));
```

Answer (score 5):

The function passed to [`array_walk()`](http://php.net/array_walk) takes 2-3 parameters.

1. Array Value (as a reference, if needed)
2. Array Key
3. Custom data (optional)

To pass multiple variables to `array_walk` pass an array.

```
array_walk($addresses, array($this, '_handle'), array('a'=>$a, 'b'=>$b));

private function _handle($address, $k, $data){
  echo $address;
  echo $data['a'];
  echo $data['b'];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `use` keyword with an anonymous function like this:

Note: $custom_var is a mixed datatype so can be an array if you want to pass several values

```
$custom_var = 'something';

array_walk( 
      $array, 
      function( &$value, $key) use ( $custom_var ){ 
    
      // Your code here, you can access the value of $custom_var
    
      });
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what i was looking for, but ill edit your answer to make it a bit clearer

Comment: @UriahsVictor thank you so much .